# How to get ComboBox.Items text value in foreach loop

Tags: c#, foreach, combobox, telerik

```
foreach (var item in cbxMeasure.Items)
{       
  var tempMeasured = item.ToString();
}
```

Program is saying that **tempMeasured's** value is `Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem`. But item has text which is what I want.

How to get text from above loop?

Thanks.

Comment: [item.Text](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/api/server/Telerik.Web.UI/RadComboBoxItem#properties-Text)?

Comment: it does not work. I have tried.

Comment: What does not work? What value do you get? Any exception?

Comment: 'object' does not contain a definition for
'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Does your combo box have more than one thing in it? repeatedly setting a value in a loop isn't much use outside of the loop like this

Comment: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found ` The error is telling you are using `RadComboBoxItem` properties on a anonymous object. Using `Foreach(RadComboBoxItem  item in cbxMeasure.Items)` will fix this simple typo error
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do the trick for you

```
foreach (RadComboBoxItem CmbItem in cbxMeasure.Items)
{
    var tempMeasured = CmbItem.Value;
}
```

Change `item.ToString();` to `item.Value`

Comment: Thanks @RandomStranger I was just going thru RadComboBoxItem properties

Comment: fubo's comment on the actual question suggests `Text` would be correct... voting to close would make more sense here.

Comment: It worked. RadComboBoxItem item is saved me. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Hi @OnurYILMAZ if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: the answer was using RadComboBoxItem  instead of var.. in the for each ..

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
var tempMeasured = item.ToString();
```

with

```
var tempMeasured =  ((RadComboBoxItem)item).Text;
```

to access the `Text` [property](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/api/server/Telerik.Web.UI/RadComboBoxItem#properties-Text).

Answer (score -2):

it should be item.get_text instead of item.ToString()